# RCPP - no matching function for call to 'transform'

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a problem while using Rcpp on Mac (on Windows the problem does not occur).

Here is the C++ Code that causes the error.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

NumericVector vecpow(const IntegerVector base, const NumericVector exp) 
{
  NumericVector out(base.size());
  std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(), exp.begin(), out.begin(), ::pow);
  return out;
}
```

Seems like nothing too fancy or complicated.

Still I get the following error when I try to compile it:

> na_ma.cpp:7:3: error: no matching function for call to 'transform'
>     std::transform(base.begin(), base.end(), exp.begin(), out.begin(), ::pow);
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:2028:1: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 5 were provided
>   transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _OutputIterator __result, _UnaryOperation __op)
>   ^

I am wondering how to fix this. While searching for solutions I came to some suggestions to create a Makevars file - but this did not work for me.

Would be also nice, if somebody could explain to me, why this error is occurring since I don't understand it.

Comment: Works for me with `g++` and `clang++` on Linux (once I add the missing lines; would be nice if you submit a complete example next time).  I suggest you check your macOS header files / added header files.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel this is more of a (older) compiler issue, just pack ::pow into lambda

Comment: Well, maybe not as OP states success on Windows where R imposes `g++` version 4.9.3.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel well, on Mac usually it is older Apple-patched clang, so one might expect differences.

Comment: I don't know. Works for me with `clang++-4.0` (the oldest one I have around) as well as the newer default.

Comment: First thanks for your help. Can't really tell you which clang version I have ... Apple has it's own versioning: clang++ --version gives Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4). The most recent 'normal' Clang version is 8.

Comment: Packing ::pow into lamda solved the problem! But I had to set Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11") to be able to use it. Which is fine, but since it is for a CRAN package it would have the disadvantage that (I guess) I now need a Makevars file with CXX_STD = CXX11 and have to set SystemRequirements: C++11 in the DESCRIPTION FILE. Is there an alternate solution, which could prevent this?

Comment: Severin Pappadeux now also addressed this in his answer. Thx :)

Comment: What’s the disadvantage of requiring C++11 for a CRAN package? In addition, newer R versions ask for other clang builds, cf https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Guess the only real disadvantage is as mentioned that you would probably have to have a Makevars file. (if you see this as disadvantage)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually C++ compiler error. Compiler cannot match ::pow with BinaryOp, so pack it into lambda. This works for me

```
std::transform(base.cbegin(), base.cend(), exp.cbegin(), out.begin(), [](double a, double b) {return ::pow(a, b); });
```

If lambdas are not available, one could try to make a functor (which lambda is equivalent to, please check https://medium.com/@winwardo/c-lambdas-arent-magic-part-1-b56df2d92ad2, https://medium.com/@winwardo/c-lambdas-arent-magic-part-2-ce0b48934809). Along the lines (untested code, I'm not at my computer)

```
struct pow_wrapper {
    public: double operator()(double a, double b) {
        return ::pow(a, b);
    }
};
```

Then try

```
std::transform(base.cbegin(), base.cend(), exp.cbegin(), out.begin(), pow_wrapper());
```

Comment: Packing ::pow into lamda solved the problem! But I had to set Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11") to be able to use it. Which is fine, but since it is for a CRAN package it would have the disadvantage that (I guess) I now need a Makevars file with CXX_STD = CXX11 and have to set SystemRequirements: C++11 in the DESCRIPTION FILE. Is there an alternate solution, which could prevent this?

Comment: @stats0007 Well, lambda is basically a functor, class with overloaded operator(). So probably yes, please check the update

Comment: Great, this completely solved my problems :) Many thanks!

Comment: One issue I overlooked is that OP used an Integer and a NumericVector, so the automatic 'cast up' into double only seems to happen with newer compiler.  I actually show the functor approach in a few tutorials but am now spoiled with C++11 being default almost everywhere ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Well, I just tried latest&greatest MSVC 19.22.27706.1 from VS 2019 preview, and it didn't compile original OP code with ::pow - cannot find overload match from transform. With either lambda or functor all goes well

Comment: The [Rcpp FAQ](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) is very clear on this; please don't expect it to work.